# Java Math convert to Integer

Tags: java, vb.net, math

I am trying to convert my float value into Integer, but I cannot convert it. It says cannot find symbol. Are there any ways to do this.

This is my java code:

```
float upper = 999999;
float lower = 100000;
Integer ReceiptNo = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();
ReceiptNo = Math.round((Math.floor( (upper - lower + 1) * rnd() ) )) + lower;
```

This is my vb code:

```
Dim upper As Single = 999999      'Set the upper limit of random number.
Dim lower As Single = 100000
Dim ReceiptNo As Integer = 0

Randomize()     'Need to randomise the random number or else the number generated is always the same
ReceiptNo = CInt(Math.Floor((upper - lower + 1) * Rnd())) + lower
```

I am trying to reuse the vb code in java. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer for the VB, note that the upper is exclusive so it needs to be 1 more that the max.

Answer (score 1):

`rnd` is an instance variable, not a method, so you can't write `rnd()`.

You can write :

```
ReceiptNo = (int)(Math.round((Math.floor( (upper - lower + 1) * Math.random() ) )) + lower);
```

I'm not sure what `Rnd()` does in VB, but if it produces a random double between 0 and 1, that's what `Math.random()` does.

Comment: so how can i do the same as in VB? because i saw in the website there was a way something like this...
`Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
      log("Generated : " + randomInt);`

Comment: it says float cannot be converted to integer

Comment: @raaj5671 sorry, add a casting to int - `(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random()` instead of `rnd()`.
You need to cast the value from `Math.round` (it's returning `float`) to `int`

```
ReceiptNo = (int) (Math.round((Math.floor( (upper - lower + 1) * Math.random() ) )) + lower);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that should be rnd.nextFloat() instead of rnd()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim prng As New Random 'do NOT put this in a method
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim upper As Integer = 999999 + 1      'Set the upper limit of random number.
    Dim lower As Integer = 100000
    Dim ReceiptNo As Integer = prng.Next(lower, upper) 'the upper is exclusive
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`rnd` here is an object of the class Random. Objects can't be used as `rnd()`. 
The correct code should be `ReceiptNo = Math.round((Math.floor( (upper - lower + 1) * Math.random() ) )) + lower;`

For more learning on java classes and objects here is good   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm